# Optimize LINQ Count() > X

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

Question: given `IEnumerable<>`, how to check what sequence contains more than `x` items?

---

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = Test().Where(o => o > 2 && o < 6); // ToList()
    if (test.Count() > 1) // how to optimize this?
        foreach (var t in test) // consumer
            Console.WriteLine(t);
}

static IEnumerable<int> Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        yield return i;
}
```

The problem here is what `Count()` will run complete sequence and that's `1E6`+ items (`ToList()` is also bad idea). I am also not allowed to change consumer code (it's a method accepting complete sequence).

Comment: What about `Any`?

Comment: `Any()` should be fine surely? `Count()` enumerates the entire collection unlike `Any` which determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

Comment: @Pikoh, my bad, `Any()` was running sequence until first item what will match `Where()` conditions. Yes, `Any()` will do for case when `x = 1`.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. Always good seeing high-rep users looking for duplicates rather than eking out a few more points answering them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case of *large* `test` collection (when `Count()` is *expensive*) you can try a typical trick:

```
if (test.Skip(1).Any())
```

In *general case* `test.Count() > x` can be rewritten into

```
if (test.Skip(x).Any())
```

**Edit**: you may want to *hide* such a tricks in a *method*, say `EnsureCount`:

```
  public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> EnsureCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

      if (count <= 0)
        foreach (var item in source)
          yield return item;
      else {
        List<T> buffer = new List<T>(count);

        foreach (var item in source) {
          if (buffer == null)
            yield return item;
          else {
            buffer.Add(item);

            if (buffer.Count >= count) {
              foreach (var x in buffer)
                yield return x;

              buffer = null;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and so your code will be

```
  var test = Test()
    .Where(o => o > 2 && o < 6)
    .EnsureCount(2); // <- Count() > 1, so at least 2 items

  foreach (var t in test)
    Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Comment: This is pretty clever!

Comment: If the collection happens to have 1 item tho this would fail... `.Skip(-1)` would work but I don't understand how this 'trick' works.

Comment: @Phill: it's the expected behaviour: the code tries to optimize `test.Count() > 1` please, notice `>` not `>=`.

Comment: Ahhh I missed that. Cheers.